# remove ubuntu and install windows 7 on my computer

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

I want to know how to install windows 7 on my ubuntu computer.

First my computer was windows 8 pre-installed and then I updated to windows 10 but after I heard and read about windows 10 scamming programs, I decided to use another os so i chosed ubuntu, it was nice but when it came to programs compatibility it isn't nice :)

So i chosed to install windows 7 that is less in scamming and more powerful, i installed the iso of windows 7 ultimate 64 bit and put it on a usb by unetbootin.
Restart the computer press f12 chose the usb device but it doesn't boot it boot to my ubuntu directly :(

Comment: in your bios you need to select USB as a boot device, otherwise it will boot from the hard drive. The other reason could be that there are no bootable files in your USB, so your PC is choosing the next bootable option which is your Ubuntu.  You can use [VMplayer](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-vmware-player-on-ubuntu-11.04-linux-mint-11) on Ubuntu and install Windows 7/8/10 and use Windows features where you need

Answer (score 0):

For the record: Win7 is in many ways less feature-rich than Win10, and does not support much of the modern hardware (like USB3 ports) that your computer probably has, at least not without finding and installing third-party drivers.

According to the [UNetbootin home page](http://unetbootin.github.io/), it's not designed to work with Windows ISOs (emphasis added):

> UNetbootin doesn't use distribution-specific rules for making your live USB drive, so most **Linux ISO** files should load correctly using this option. However, not all distributions support booting from USB, and some others require extra boot options or other modifications before they can boot from USB drives, so these ISO files will not work as-is. Also, **ISO files for non-Linux operating systems have a different boot mechanism, so don't expect them to work either**.

There are a number of different suggestions on [this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu), although none of them are particularly simple and reliable. [`WinUSB`](http://en.congelli.eu/prog_info_winusb.html) looks to be the easiest, but may mess up your Ubuntu installation (your computer is new enough to be near-guaranteed of using UEFI) so make sure you heed the warnings, or you take a risk of rendering your Ubuntu unbootable just by installing WinUSB.

The easiest option may be to just use a Windows machine (owned by a friend or something). Using `diskpart`, select the flashdrive, delete its current partition, create a new one, and mark it as "active" (this means "bootable" in Windows-ese, basically). Then, simply copy the files from your ISO onto the flashdrive; you can mount the ISO or just use an extraction tool (7-Zip on Windows, `ark` or similar on Linux) to pull the files out of the ISO.